# Using a MacBook air as a monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, video-adapter

Can I use the MacBook Air as a monitor when making a video with my Iphone. I wish to use my camera app on my Iphone 5s to record  how to videos and need to be able to see on a monitor at the same time. Is this possible

Answer (score 3):

Yep,

1. Plug your iPhone into your MacBook via Lightning-to-USB cable.
2. Open QuickTime Player (it's on every Mac)
3. While QuickTime Player is running, click File in the menu bar.
4. Select "New Movie Recording" (not "New Screen Recording" like one may think)
5. Click the arrow on the right of the record button to open a dropdown
6. Select your iPhone under the camera section
7. If you want sound as well, repeat 5 & 6, but select your iPhone under "Microphone", as well

That's it! Your iPhone will have to be within USB cable length of your Mac, but you will be able to see everything on it that you will be able to see on your iPhone, and it's 100% free.

Note: mirroring the screen of your iPhone on your Mac will drain the battery life substantially

Comment: Thanks for the help. Completely forgot I had used this channel, was still looking and today I came across your answer ,Had already tried to connect using quick time and although it worked on my IMac it just would not work on the MBAir Will give it a try ...watch this space...